# Where can I find an online version of Lorenzo Valla’s latin translation of Histories by Herodotus?

Tags: latin-language

Where can I find an online version of Lorenzo Valla’s latin translation of The Histories by Herodotus?

I want to read Valla's Latin translation, not a translation into English.

Comment: Where have you looked already?

Comment: I've looked all over the internet with a variety of searches. I seem to be living in an English ghetto as far as online Latin is concerned. I know there are copies of Valla's translation at Yale, near me, but I would like to find this online so I can quickly search it.

Comment: Is [this](https://archive.org/details/bub_gb_BDm_darB0y0C/page/n3) it? (I can't read Latin so...)

Comment: @SteveBird  That looks like the right one to me (at least, it matches what the OP has asked for).  Of course, how searchable it is depends on the quality of the OCR scanning, but that is an entirely different question.

Comment: That's very good. Not searchable, but it saves me a trip to the library! Thanks.

Comment: Turns out it is searchable and I found exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much.